# How can I convert serialized data in boost::beast to a string so that I could process it in a FIFO manner?

Tags: c++, http, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

I have an application of a client where I need to receive http "long running requests" from a server. I send a command, and after getting the header of the response, I have to just receive json data separated by `\r\n` until the connection is terminated.

I managed to adapt [boost beast client example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/example/http/client/async/http_client_async.cpp) to send the message and receive the header and parse it and receive responses from the server. However, I failed at finding a way to serialize the data so that I could process the json messages.

The closest demonstration of the problem can be found in [this relay example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/more_examples/http_relay.html). In that example (`p` is a parser, `sr` is a serializer, `input` is a socket input stream and `output` is an socket output stream), after reading the http header, we have a loop that reads continuously from the server:

```
do
{
    if(! p.is_done())
    {
        // Set up the body for writing into our small buffer
        p.get().body().data = buf;
        p.get().body().size = sizeof(buf);

        // Read as much as we can
        read(input, buffer, p, ec);

        // This error is returned when buffer_body uses up the buffer
        if(ec == error::need_buffer)
            ec = {};
        if(ec)
            return;

        // Set up the body for reading.
        // This is how much was parsed:
        p.get().body().size = sizeof(buf) - p.get().body().size;
        p.get().body().data = buf;
        p.get().body().more = ! p.is_done();
    }
    else
    {
        p.get().body().data = nullptr;
        p.get().body().size = 0;
    }

    // Write everything in the buffer (which might be empty)
    write(output, sr, ec);

    // This error is returned when buffer_body uses up the buffer
    if(ec == error::need_buffer)
        ec = {};
    if(ec)
        return;
}
while(! p.is_done() && ! sr.is_done());
```

A few things I don't understand here:

1. We're done reading the header. Why do we need boost beast and not boost asio to read a raw tcp message? When I tried to do that (with both async_read/async_read_some) I got an infinite reads of zero size.
2. The documentation of [parser](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__http__parser.html) says (at the end of the page) that a new instance is needed for every message, but I don't see that in the example.
3. Since tcp message reading is not working, is there a way to convert the parser/serializer data to some kind of string? Even write it to a text file in a FIFO manner, so that I could process it with some json library? I don't want to use another socket like the example.

The function `boost::beast::buffers()` failed to compile for the parser and the serializer, and for the parser there's no consume function, and the serializer's consume seems to be for particular http parts of the message, which fires an assert if I do it for `body()`.

Besides that, I also failed at getting consistent chunks of data from the parser and the buffer with old-school `std::copy`. I don't seem to understand how to combine the data together to get the stream of data. Consuming the buffer with `.consume()` at any point while receiving data leads to `need buffer` error.

I would really appreciate someone explaining the logic of how all this should work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is `buf`? You could read directly into the `std::string` instead. Call `string.resize(N)`, and set the pointer and size in the `buffer_body::value_type` to `string.data()` and `string.size()`.

Comment: IIUYC, the only change it would do is replace `buf` with a `string`. But then this isn't where I'm having trouble. I'm having trouble after the serializer. Instead of having the serializer be written to a socket (as shown in the example I copied from http_relay), I'd like it to go to a string/view. You mentioned chunking before and it's a legitimate concern. Especially that, in all my attempts to convert anything to a string, I'm having repeated parts of the data. Can you please write a little snippet of code that replaces `write(output, sr, ec);` to something that'll convert `sr` to a string?

Comment: You want to convert the HTTP message into a string? Use `operator<<` to `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Thanks, Vinnie. I think I understand how it works now. I don't need a serializer. I misunderstood the documentation. The serializer is not necessary because I don't want to submit to a socket. I just needed the parser. Once I used a `string_body` in the parser template parameter, everything became easy and everything worked fine. The only problem left is that since it's chunked and the steam never ends, the parser content just keeps growing indefinitely. Is there a way to clear/consume its string content? (other than recreating the connection)

Comment: The only clear function I found is for individual body objects, not everything in the parser. An issue is that for some reason, in `body()`, all terminators `\r\n` were non-existent. I was able to circumvent this problem by using the `payload_size()`, where I read a body, parse it with json if parsable, and then clear the body() string. No idea why terminators are disappearing. I can live with that as long as messages/read callbacks will not be combined, otherwise that will sabotage json parsing. If I'm doing any of this incorrectly, please let me know. Best.

Comment: You won't see the chunked encoding delimiters because Beast's parser removes them before appending the data to the string. As I said already, use `buffer_body` if you want to parse a never-ending response incrementally.

Comment: I will do that next. I have a working starting point now where I can optimize things to the fullest and know what to expect. Thanks again and have a nice day :-)